# OpenVPN + Samba share not working on very fast connection

Tags: openvpn, samba

I have a server running ClearOS with OpenVPN and Samba shares (flexshares) enabled. Client machines are able to connect to the OpenVPN server from a remote location, and are able to see all shares on the server without issues (tested), except in one particular location where the internet speed is at least 200 Mbit down, possibly as fast as 350 Mbit. Server is on 10 Mbit up, 15 Mbit down speed. At this particular location, the client machine is able to connect to the OpenVPN server, but when viewing shares on the server, only 1 shared folder shows up labeled "Share", rather than the expected folders that actually exist on the server. Client machines run Windows 7.

The question is, can this very high speed at this particular location be the cause of not seeing Samba shares, considering everything works fine when the client is at other locations (with a slower speed)? Or could there be another explanation, perhaps ISP issues or similar?

Answer (score 0):

The speed will not be the problem here.

There might be a conflict, where the same IP address or hostname appears in two places, and you're not actually reaching the machine you think you're reaching.

Comment: Ok. It's a simple setup, so I don't expect IP address conflicts, but I'll try pinging the server while disconnected from OpenVPN to see if I get anywhere. Any other thoughts?